# How to "theme" a Navigation Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-8

I'm having some difficulty trying to figure out how to "theme" the main navigation menu in Drupal 8 using Bootstrap.  It seems as though the Drupal 8 themes engine overrides anything I try in Bootstrap.

I am trying to make it look something like this:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role = "navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
            <li><a href = "#">ITEM ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">ITEM TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">ITEM THREE</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">ITEM FOUR</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Basically I just want the menu to be fixed to the bottom, to be justified with equal spacing between each menu link, and to be the same width as the container size (not the width of the page).  I have spent two days trying to figure out which part I need to edit, and I have no clue anymore.

Thank you to any brilliant person that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some experience of Drupal7, you can find if it applies to Drupal8.

```
$ find . -type f |grep page\.tpl\.php
./modules/block/tests/themes/block_test_theme/page.tpl.php
./modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php
./modules/system/page.tpl.php
./sites/all/modules/ctools/page_manager/theme/page-manager-edit-page.tpl.php
./themes/bartik/templates/maintenance-page.tpl.php
./themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php
./themes/garland/maintenance-page.tpl.php
./themes/garland/page.tpl.php
./themes/seven/maintenance-page.tpl.php
./themes/seven/page.tpl.php
```

From the output above, you can find out that the default template file for a page is `./modules/system/page.tpl.php`, you will never change it, while it has beautiful document about how to customize this template.

Then check the command output again, you can find the templates provided by the embeded themes, e.g. `./themes/bartik/templates/page.tpl.php`. Comparing these two file, you would get an idea of how a Theme overrides the default. Then you can easily copy anyone to your custom Theme, and put the html in.

But it's just for Drupal7, I have not dig into much in Drupal8, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but Drupal 8 uses a different themes engine (called twig), and the files don't make any sense because I've edited `/<drupalroot>/themes/bootstrap/templates/menu/menu.html.twig` and nothing worked.

Comment: You have to clear cache after each change of template. Not sure if you missed the step. Again the command in Drupal7 is `drush cc all`

Comment: UGH!  You solved it.  I did everything else right, I just didn't clear cache.  I'll mark your answer as right.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Drupal 8** uses a newer themes layout engine called **twig**.  If you've created a sub-theme, you can edit the layout using the twig files located in the **`<drupalroot>/themes/bootstrap/templates`** folder.  Copy any edited files to: **`<drupalroot>/themes/<bootstrap-sub-theme>/templates`** folder and then clear the cache in drupal: **`Administration > Configuration > Development > Performance`**

Here's the completed code in case anyone struggles like I did:

**FILENAME:** menu--main.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
  * Default theme implementation to display a menu.
  *
  * Available variables:
  * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
  * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
  *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
  *   - below: The menu item child items.
  *   - title: The menu link title.
  *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
  *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
  *
  * @ingroup templates
  */
 #}
 {% import _self as menus %}

 {#
   We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
   @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
 #}
 {{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

 {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
   {% import _self as menus %}
   {% if items %}
     {% if menu_level == 0 %}
     <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
       <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav', 'container') }} style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
     {% else %}
       <ul{{ attributes.addClass('dropdown-menu') }}>
     {% endif %}
     {% for item in items %}
       {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
         <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('expanded', 'dropdown') }}>
         <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
       {% else %}
         <li{{ item.attributes }}>
         {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
       {% endif %}
       {% if item.below %}
         {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav', 'navbar-nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
       {% endif %}
       </li>
     {% endfor %}

     </ul>
         </div>
   {% endif %}
 {% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 1):

agree with @user2470057

and you have one more option to override template:

1. Open Website in chrome
2. Inspect element in navigation menu
3. you will see some template suggestions which will override default template. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6HP.jpg)
4. these are the available template override suggestions.
5. create a file named one of the suggestions in "themes/your_theme/templates/filename.html.twig

Comment: OK, that actually helped a little.  I have this as the current <header>
    <header class="navbar navbar-default container" id="navbar" role="banner">  
if I add navbar-fixed-bottom to the <header> it solves 90% of the problem.  Where in the templates does the <header> tag reside?

Comment: <header> tag is for header of the webpage. So it will not available in the template which you are using for override a block.

To do this: follow these steps (If you are using drupal 8 Bootstrap theme as base theme ):

1. Copy file themes/bootstrap/templates/system/page.html.twig
and paste to themes/your_child_theme/templates dir.

In this new page.html.twig file you can add your class "navbar-fixed-bottom" to variable navbar_classes ( at line 70 [according to my file] ).

clear cache.

It will work.